# Is elemental damage on a legendary gem affected by elemental damage on gear?

Tags: diablo-iii

Some of the new legendary gems, such as [Mirinae, Teaerdrop of the Starweaver](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/mirinae-teardrop-of-the-starweaver), cause elemental damage to occur (2000% weapon damage in this case). If I have +Holy damage on my gear, will this increase the amount of damage of this gem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the elemental damage dealt by the gem ends up being increased by elemental damage gear.

The +Holy damage gear you have will not affect the gem's listed damage, but it will affect the end result. The gem will still hit for 2000% (or more depending on the rank). Leveling gems increases the value of the blue text on the gem, so this one will increase every level - not sure of the exact increase.

However, once the 2000% weapon damage as holy is calculated, the additional holy damage from your gear will be added on. Essentially, if you do 500,000 in white damage per hit, then this gem should hit for 10,000,000 in holy. If you have +20% holy damage, then the resulting hit should be 12,000,000.

Edit, some screen shots

Here is a normal white hit, as seen it is 290k

[image]

Here is a normal crit, 1.2m

[image]

The range seems to be roughly 250-350k on my character for white hits, and 800k-1.6m for crits. I am bringing this up because with 75% crit, the holy gem seems to only crit.

So, with 0% holy damage, this is what the crit from the gem looks like, 19m

[image]

And this is what the hit from the gem looks like (the crit was from my plain attack, the white is the gem), 3.9m

[image]

Okay so all of that was prior to the holy damage, I am now going to put on 20% and repeat the process:

[image]

As you can see, yes, the damage modifier does factor in, holy damage on gear increases the damage done by this gem.

Elemental damage is also discussed in length on the battle.net forums for d3. Here is a [green post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11986398637) discussing it, and in the [2.1.0 patch notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/15487814/patch-210-now-live-8-26-2014#bugfixitems)

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @Frank - It is the same way that all elemental damage calculations work. The modification is done after the original damage is calculated. I guess my source would be 500 paragon levels of playing, in other words, I am an expert on this topic. If you want a green post from the forums, see here: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11986398637 . Another way of looking at this would be to just multiply the 2000 * 1.2, and then take that 2400% of the holy damage, still yielding the 12m in the example.

Comment: Thing is, though, that many legendary weapons that had elemental damage, were not actually benefitting from +to elemental.  Should they have?  Yeah.  Were they?  Nope.  That's why I'm asking for a source, as there is previous behaviour to suggest this may not be the case.  I think it *should*, yeah, but I'm not seeing anything here that says it *does*.

Comment: @Frank - Hm, so you think it is a bug? I have this gem, when I get home I will run some tests with screenshots. Do note though, that what you point out isn't really what the OP asked in their question.

Comment: We haven't gotten anything from the devs to say yes or no, I don't think.  But if you want to do some empirical testing, that I'd definitely accept as a source.  It may or may not be a bug, if gems don't benefit from +elemental.  I'm pointing at previous behaviour to draw a conclusion about what is or isn't likely.  Personally, I think the gems should benefit from the +elemental, but I'm not going to assume that it works that logically.

Comment: @Frank According to the 2.1.0 patch notes, legendary items that do elemental damage are now affected by +elemental damage on gear: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/15487814/patch-210-now-live-8-26-2014#bugfixitems . So I bet legendary gems fall under this as well, if I had to guess.

Comment: @Frank Looks like Travis is correct. I tested this by using a Wreath of Lightning with and without +Lightning damage gear, and it on average did significantly more damage when I had the +Lightning damage gear equipped.

Comment: @Adeese Works for me!  I just figured that it might have worked the silly way before.

Comment: @Frank - See edit for screenshots :)